# How do I sync a windows mobile application when attached?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, synchronization

I'm writing a windows mobile application which will be running on a PDA, not a smartphone.  It will also be used in an area with spotty wifi reception, so I need to be able to sync the data on the application when it is connected to another computer.  What APIs or frameworks should I look into to perform this?  I've looked at RDA and Sync Framework, but they both seem to require a network connection on the device.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSync was the "original" Windows Mobile sync framework.  Basic sync operations can be done with [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920274.aspx). A [managed wrapper exists](http://rapi.codeplex.com/) for that API.

A full-blown [ActiveSync Serivice Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861261.aspx) can be created for full, true sync operations, but it must be written in C++.

Also bear in mind that for most new devices, the USB connection *is* an RNDIS network connection, and things like the sync framework will work with it.